# How to continue after recieving an error on a stream in RxJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs

I have a service in Node.js that retrieves the mail servers for an email address:

```
export interface IHasEmail {
    email: string;
}

export interface IHasMailServer extends IHasEmail {
    mailServers: Array<string>
}

export interface IMailServerService {
    lookupMailServers( contact: IHasEmail ): RX.Observable<IHasMailServer>;
}
```

I have an array of contacts (IHasEmail) and I want to retrieve the mail servers for the whole list. So far I have this:

```
checkContacts( contacts: Array<contracts.IContact> ): void {

    Rx.Observable.from(contacts).flatMap<contracts.IHasMailServer>( (contact) => {
        return this._mailServerService.lookupMailServers( contact )
    } ).subscribe(
        (result) => this.handleResult(result),
        (error) => this.handleError( error )
    );
}
```

This works fine until an error is returned from one of the calls to lookupMailServer. At this point no more results are returned to handleResults.

I want to log the error but continue to receive the successful results from the other contacts. How do I do this?

The code for this example can be seen here:

https://github.com/Roaders/contact-list-checker/tree/4dd0146449a4be6e703a9b60034231cc4c4bdea3

Comment: You need to handle the error explicitly. Create a new observable that handles it, and maps it to something like `{error: Error, result: IHasMailServer}`. Then using this observable, filter it by `error == null` and do logging. Filter it by `error != null` and do whatever you do in your stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions are terminal events for `Observables`. If an internal one errors than it will bubble up to the outer `Observable` and gets forwarded all the way downstream. You need to `catch` or otherwise `retry` the intermediate exception just like you would in synchronous code.

```
checkContacts( contacts: Array<contracts.IContact> ): void {

    Rx.Observable.from(contacts).flatMap<contracts.IHasMailServer>( (contact) => {
        return this._mailServerService.lookupMailServers( contact )
                 //If it is a cold source than retrying the method will
                 //re-invoke the method, just in case you suffered something like a transient network error.
                 .retry(3)
                 .catch((err) => {
                   //Log the error message here
                   //Then return an empty Observable which will get removed
                   //during the subsequent flattening.
                   return isFatal(err) ? Rx.Observable.throw(err) : Rx.Observable.empty();
                 });
    } ).subscribe(
        (result) => this.handleResult(result),
        (error) => this.handleError( error )
    );
}
```

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. I did remove the source argument as that produced Typescript compilation errors. Works great.